# Spring security does not generate session cookie for postman but does for chrome

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, spring-cloud-gateway

I have Spring Cloud Gateway working with KeyCloak as OpenId connect provider. If I hit a REST endpoint on the gateway (and not on some backend service) using Postman, it does not generate a Session Cookie when I hit the endpoint. However, if I hit the same endpoint using the Chrome browser, the response to that end-point generates a session cookie. As a result, request caching does not work with Postman but works with chrome. I'vent tried hitting a REST endpoint on the backend yet, but it is not clear why it would work with the browser and not with Postman (linux client). The keycloak authentication part is working fine.

e.g. When I try to hit localhost:8080/live using postman, no session cookie is generated for that request and the user-agent gets re-directed to localhost:8080/oauth2/authorization/keycloak-registration (on the same gateway service). This endpoint then redirects to keycloak (authorization endpoint) and sets a session cookie. However, since this endpoint is oblivious to the original request, no request caching happens; it just redirects to "/" on the gateway on subsequent authentication success.

OTOH, if I use chrome, my original request (to /live), generates a session cookie and redirect to localhost:8080/oauth2/authorization/keycloak-registration does not generate any additional session cookie. Subsequent authentication interactions with keycloak work fine and request caching works.

My Spring Security configuration is as follows. Interestingly, unlike HttpSecurity in Spring MVC, ServerHttpSecurity does not provide any knobs for session management. So, I can't figure out how to make the behavior uniform across user-agents in a deterministic way.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
public class AndurilSecurityConfig {
    
    @Bean
    public SecurityWebFilterChain springSecurityFilterChain(ServerHttpSecurity http) {
        http.authorizeExchange(exchanges -> exchanges.anyExchange().authenticated())
            .oauth2Login(withDefaults())
            .requestCache();
        
        http.csrf().disable();

        
        return http.build();
    }
}
```

Relevant excerpts from application.yml with some redactions,

```
spring.cloud.gateway:
  httpclient:
    wiretap: true
  httpserver:
    wiretap: true
  default-filters:
  - name: BasicAuthFilter
  routes:
    - id: adminservice
      uri: http://${ADMIN_SERVICE}/
      predicates:
        - Path=/admin/**
    - id: appservice
      uri: http://${APP_SERVICE}/
      predicates:
        - Path=/app/**
spring.security.oauth2.client:
  provider:
    keycloak:
      issuer-uri: http://${AUTHSERVER}/auth/realms/${REALM}
      user-name-attribute: preferred_username
  registration:
    keycloak-registration:
      provider: keycloak
      client-id: ${CLIENT_ID}
      client-secret: ${CLIENT_SECRET}
      authorization-grant-type: authorization_code
      redirect-uri: "{baseUrl}/login/oauth2/code/keycloak"
```

It seems the issue is with MediaTypes. For some reason, `*/*` is being rejected/ignored but `text/html` works fine. It is not clear why MediaTypes would have any role to play in Request Caching.

```
WITH CHROME:
-------------------------------------------
03:59:49.049 reactor-http-epoll-2 DEBUG anduril NegatedServerWebExchangeMatcher: matches = true
03:59:49.049 reactor-http-epoll-2 DEBUG anduril AndServerWebExchangeMatcher: Trying to match using MediaTypeRequestMatcher [matchingMediaTypes=[text/html], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[*/*]]
03:59:49.049 reactor-http-epoll-2 DEBUG anduril MediaTypeServerWebExchangeMatcher: httpRequestMediaTypes=[text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/avif, image/webp, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8]
03:59:49.049 reactor-http-epoll-2 DEBUG anduril MediaTypeServerWebExchangeMatcher: Processing text/html
03:59:49.049 reactor-http-epoll-2 DEBUG anduril MediaTypeServerWebExchangeMatcher: text/html .isCompatibleWith text/html = true
03:59:49.049 reactor-http-epoll-2 DEBUG anduril AndServerWebExchangeMatcher: All requestMatchers returned true
03:59:49.049 reactor-http-epoll-2 DEBUG anduril WebSessionServerRequestCache: Request added to WebSession: '/live'
03:59:49.049 reactor-http-epoll-2 DEBUG anduril DefaultServerRedirectStrategy: Redirecting to '/oauth2/authorization/keycloak-registration'
03:59:49.049 reactor-http-epoll-2 DEBUG anduril PathPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher: Checking match of request : '/oauth2/authorization/keycloak-registration'; against '/oauth2/authorization/{registrationId}'



WITH POSTMAN USING */*:
-------------------------------------------
04:30:44.044 parallel-3 DEBUG anduril NegatedServerWebExchangeMatcher: matches = true
04:30:44.044 parallel-3 DEBUG anduril AndServerWebExchangeMatcher: Trying to match using MediaTypeRequestMatcher [matchingMediaTypes=[text/html], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[*/*]]
04:30:44.044 parallel-3 DEBUG anduril MediaTypeServerWebExchangeMatcher: httpRequestMediaTypes=[*/*]
04:30:44.044 parallel-3 DEBUG anduril MediaTypeServerWebExchangeMatcher: Processing */*
04:30:44.044 parallel-3 DEBUG anduril MediaTypeServerWebExchangeMatcher: Ignoring
04:30:44.044 parallel-3 DEBUG anduril MediaTypeServerWebExchangeMatcher: Did not match any media types
04:30:44.044 parallel-3 DEBUG anduril AndServerWebExchangeMatcher: Did not match
04:30:44.044 parallel-3 DEBUG anduril DefaultServerRedirectStrategy: Redirecting to '/oauth2/authorization/keycloak-registration'
04:30:44.044 reactor-http-epoll-4 DEBUG anduril PathPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher: Checking match of request : '/oauth2/authorization/keycloak-registration'; against '/oauth2/authorization/{registrationId}'



WITH POSTMAN USING text/html:
-------------------------------------------
04:47:30.030 parallel-1 DEBUG anduril NegatedServerWebExchangeMatcher: matches = true
04:47:30.030 parallel-1 DEBUG anduril AndServerWebExchangeMatcher: Trying to match using MediaTypeRequestMatcher [matchingMediaTypes=[text/html], useEquals=false, ignoredMediaTypes=[*/*]]
04:47:30.030 parallel-1 DEBUG anduril MediaTypeServerWebExchangeMatcher: httpRequestMediaTypes=[text/html]
04:47:30.030 parallel-1 DEBUG anduril MediaTypeServerWebExchangeMatcher: Processing text/html
04:47:30.030 parallel-1 DEBUG anduril MediaTypeServerWebExchangeMatcher: text/html .isCompatibleWith text/html = true
04:47:30.030 parallel-1 DEBUG anduril AndServerWebExchangeMatcher: All requestMatchers returned true
04:47:30.030 parallel-1 DEBUG anduril WebSessionServerRequestCache: Request added to WebSession: '/live'
04:47:30.030 parallel-1 DEBUG anduril DefaultServerRedirectStrategy: Redirecting to '/oauth2/authorization/keycloak-registration'
04:47:30.030 reactor-http-epoll-3 DEBUG anduril PathPatternParserServerWebExchangeMatcher: Checking match of request : '/oauth2/authorization/keycloak-registration'; against '/oauth2/authorization/{registrationId}'
```

Comment: I thought to answer your question, but I read it backwards so I deleted the answer. What host are you using to interact with keycloak? Is it `localhost`, or an external host?

Comment: Hi Steve thanks for looking into it. I'm using docker (compose). Both, Spring Cloud Gateway and Keycloak are running as containers. However, the gateway sees keycloak as an external host (using extra_host field from docker-compose). The whole setup (including postman & browser) run on my linux desktop. I use an entry in /etc/hosts of my linux desktop to DNS resolve  the keycloak hostname. It's not clear why the behavior would differ between postman and chrome.

Comment: Can you provide your spring cloud gateway config? My guess is there's an issue with the way routes are being configured or a conflict between cookies set by different hosts behind the gateway, but it's hard to tell without knowing those details.

Comment: Hi Steve. I've added the SCG config. The BasicAuthFilter is for Basic authentication with the stateless backend services; this will be eventually replaced with OAuth2 access token.  For now, I'm just using KeyCloak for identity verification. Also, I'm accessing/testing end-points local to the SCG (and not on the backend). This local endpoint (e.g. localhost:/live) is the very first URL that I'm hitting. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see where you added that.

Comment: Sorry, Steve. Looks like I forgot to save the edits. I've added application.yml. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Steve. The issue seems to be with MediaTypes. It is not clear why it would matter. Please check the attached logs. Thanks.

Comment: Yep, you pretty much figured it out as I answered. But there you go! :)

Answer (score 1):

Based on your config, I was able to rule out anything related to Spring Cloud Gateway and OAuth 2.0 support. This is a more subtle behavior with the default request cache implementation `WebSessionServerRequestCache`.

TL;DR — If you add `Accept: text/html` to your headers in Postman, it should work.

The request cache in Spring Security's webflux support is designed (similar to servlet) to apply only to web requests from a browser. Since Postman is not exactly a browser, it does not fall into the case supported by Spring Security out of the box, which explains why your behavior is different in Postman. Command line clients like curl would fall into this category as well, as would native apps, etc.

Postman sends an `Accept` header of `*/*` by default, I assume in an attempt to say "Give me any response." Spring Security ignores this and further specifically expects the `Accept` header to be `text/html`, which is sent in a typical browser request. See [these lines](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/28747ca89c882dadb385541d68a39579771a7d56/web/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/web/server/savedrequest/WebSessionServerRequestCache.java#L105-L112).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, Steve; that really helps. The (default) Request Caching policy makes sense. Any idea, what is the policy for generating session cookie?

Comment: I believe it is a side effect of the request cache, among other things (such as saving a csrf token).

Comment: True Steve. There is no need to generate a state/session, if there is nothing to remember. :)

Comment: BTW, I'm seeing other issues with SCG & Spring Security. Can I please bring them to your attention? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70990403/spring-security-oauth2-oidc-rp-initiated-logout-does-not-work. I think Josh Cummings was looking at it, but may be he missed my reply over the weekend.

Comment: Would you mind upvoting and/or accepting the answer if it helped you? I'm sure Josh will get to it when he finds time. We don't typically check SO on the weekend, but I happened so I thought I'd reply.

Comment: No problem, Steve. I tried upvoting but it says I need more reputation points. However, it has recorded my vote. Thanks for all your help.